# A simple geometry problem

Tags: geometry

In the figure given below, O is the centre of the circle and angle BCO=40 degrees. Find x, y and z, if DO and CE are both perpendicular  to AE.
[image]

Comment: Your Question's title does not describe the question at all

Comment: Yeah... there are thousands of "Simple geometry problem"s on MathStack already and it's hard to figure out what are they about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Z - you see how the circumference captured by the two rays forming Z is 270 degrees? Z = 135.

X - draw line BO. Angle BOE is 50 degrees, you see why? It follows that X is 25.

Y - angle COD is also 40 (alternate interior angles forms by transversal thru parallel lines). With and arc of length 40, Y is 20 degrees.

This is geometry that follows from a set of rules regarding angles within a circle. If you are working from a textbook, the rules should be summarized toward the end.

[image]

For your problem, it's these two rules that mostly apply. (a) the central angle with vertex at the circle center, has the same measure as its intercepted arc. (b) the angle with vertex on the circumference has half the measure of the intercepted arc.

Your angle Z for example, is example 2, vertex on the circumference, and the angle is half the measure of the intercepted arc, i.e. 1/2 * 270.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't understand how you are able to get these answers

Comment: Can you add a note here or to question describing the background to this? Are you a parent, student, other? Where did problem come from?

Comment: I am a student and the problem came from an exam which i took recently but was not able to answer

Comment: I added the main 2 rules and illustrations for each.